# not getting dynamically added input field cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

my add.ctp

```
<input name="data[Language][0][name]" type="text" maxlength="50" id="Language0Language">
```

and I added one more field dynamically using jquery from add.ctp
like

```
<input name="data[Language][1][name]" type="text" maxlength="50" id="Language1Language">
<input name="data[Language][2][name]" type="text" maxlength="50" id="Language2Language">
```

when debug:

```
debug($this->data);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [language] => english
            [speak] => 1
            [wright] => 1
            [read] => 0
        )

)
```

newly added field not showing in the list!.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try with the security component disabled and see if it works.

Comment: does `data[Language][0][name]` show in your debug? what about in `print_r($_POST)`? Cake can do some weird things with form elements that aren't added using the form helper and often it can come down to syntax errors somewhere

Comment: i tried security component disabled still not working..(debug results updated)

Answer (score 1):

This is because, the security component will validate POST data. It will remove all dynamic fields. So to allow dynamic fields, add the following line in beforeFilter() of the respective controller.

```
  function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Security->validatePost=false;
  }
```

Comment: still same issue (with print_r $_post also)

Comment: Can you check whether all fields are POSTed by seeing "request headers " in chrome?

Comment: not showing in request headers too.. ( the dynamically added fields..! ). i'm using cakephp 1.3