# CakePHP 2.x - Dynamically adding & removing form element

Tags: jquery, forms, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In a project, I have a form, where I have to add & remove some elements in the form dynamically. So, I did it using jQuery. But when the form submits, it just gets value from the existing elements, completely ignoring the newer ones.

At last what I did, I added some more elements to the form and hide them. Then when a button is clicked, the next hidden element becomes visible. When another button is clicked, the new elements(those were hidden) go hidden again.

This way I can show the user that the elements are dynamically added & deleted, but I dont like this way. And, there are some redundant data from the hidden fields go to the db, all values are null.

My problem is like this one : [not getting dynamically added input field cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479085/not-getting-dynamically-added-input-field-cakephp)

So I tried this in my `AppController` :

```
$this->Security->validatePost=false;
```

But, as I am not using `Security Component` in my project, it shows error.

So what should I do now ?

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: you have to show us some code that you are using, if you are not using security component you can ignore the line `$this->Security->validatePost=false;`

Comment: When saving, what do you get in $this-request ?

Comment: As I said, $this->request only gives the values from the existing form elements(hidden or visible whatever they are), null values too. But I want the values from the instantly added new form elements also. @AshHimself

Comment: Well, I think this problem doesn't need much code to explain. I think what is the main concern here is how to validate the new elements in cakephp/how to make the new values available to the returned array. I think there is a little thing that I don't know. That's why I didn't give much code here. Well, if you need, I'll add some more code.@Abhishek